# Cannot set default emacs color theme in .emacs file

Tags: emacs

I searched everywhere and mostly people suggest the following code for setting a default color theme:

```
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-name)
```

However, this doesn't work. When I start emacs I get this error:

> Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading
>   `/home/epsilonvector/.emacs':
>
> Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-name
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

This happens for every theme name, even ones whose correctness I'm sure of.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to insert `(color-theme-initialize)` in between the require and the call to the theme name.

Comment: This just rescued me from a lot of frustration.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First, `color-theme` is a package that you have to install; I don't believe it's included in any version of emacs. The download link is [here.](http://download.savannah.nongnu.org/releases/color-theme/)

Second, you're not supposed to literally use the symbol `color-theme-name`, but rather the name of the color scheme: `color-theme-hober`, for example.

Comment: I have color-theme, and I meant color-theme-<name>, as in color-theme-the-name-of-the-theme-I-want (Didn't know color-theme-name was a defined symbol when I wrote this).

Comment: @EpsilonVector: from the error message "Symbol's function definition is void: color-theme-name" its evident that you `evaled color-theme-name` rather than substituting `name` for the actual theme name.